# Is it possible to use mysql5.5 and mariaDB 10.0 in same machine?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, apt-get

I wanna install mariaDB 10.0 in server. but it's already installed mysql5.5. 
so i tried to install mariaDB to use apt-get command.

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 mariadb-client-10.0
  mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common mariadb-server-core-10.0
  mysql-common
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx mariadb-test
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient18:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libmariadbclient18 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0
  mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient18 mysql-common
2 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 8 to remove and 532 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.2 MB/37.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 25.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

i dont know why mysql packages will be REMOVED.

is it impossible?

Comment: It appears to be possible to have both MySQL and MariaDB running alongside each other, but the installation seems to be much more complex than simply using `apt-get`, q.v. [the official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/), which gives you step by step instructions.

Comment: thank you. but that link is not worked for me. i tried to start mariadb server. it didn't start. my prompt print 

Starting MySQL 
. *

and it's just done. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find the all step to install mariadb alongside mysql in mariadb website:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/